# Proving Bonnets' Recursion with Rodrigues' Formula

Tags: special-functions, orthogonal-polynomials, legendre-polynomials

I would like to show that $(n+1)P_{n+1}(x)+nP_{n-1}(x)=(2n+1)xP_{n}(x)$ using Rodrigues' formula, not the generating function.

I got to this point, but have not been able to progress further.

$$(n+1)P_{n+1}(x)=\frac{x(n+1)(D^{n}(x^{2}-1)^{n})+n(n+1)(D^{n-1}(x^{2}-1)^{n})}{2^{n}n!}$$

$D^{n}$ denotes the $n^{th}$ derivative with respect to $x$.

I see that part of the $(2n+1)xP_{n}(x)$ term is formed in the first term of the fraction, but do not see how to recover the rest of Bonnets' recursion.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using Rodrigues' formula $\displaystyle P_n(x)=\frac{1}{2^n n!}D^n\left(x^2-1\right)^n$, we can write
\begin{align*}
&\color{blue}{\left(n+1\right)P_{n+1}(x)}-\color{green}{\left(2n+1\right)xP_n(x)}+\color{red}{nP_{n-1}(x)}=\\
=\;&\frac{1}{2^{n+1}n!}D^{n-1}\biggl\{\color{blue}{D^2\left(x^2-1\right)^{n+1}}+\color{red}{4n^2\left(x^2-1\right)^{n-1}}\biggr\}-\color{green}{\left(2n+1\right)xP_n(x)}=\\
=\;&\frac{1}{2^{n+1}n!}D^{n-1}\biggl\{\left(x^2-1\right)^{n-1}\biggl[
\color{blue}{4n\left(n+1\right)x^2+2\left(n+1\right)\left(x^2-1\right)}+\color{red}{4n^2}\biggr]\biggr\}-\color{green}{\left(2n+1\right)xP_n(x)}=\\
=\;&\frac{2n+1}{2^{n}n!}D^{n-1}\biggl\{\left(x^2-1\right)^{n-1}\biggl[
\left(n+1\right)x^2+n-1\biggr]\biggr\}-\color{green}{\frac{2n+1}{2^{n}n!}xD^{n}\left(x^2-1\right)^n}.
\end{align*}
Now observe that $[D,x]=1$ implies $[D^n,x]=nD^{n-1}$. Using this to replace $xD^n$ in the above expression by $D^n\circ x-nD^{n-1}$, we can rewrite it as
\begin{align}
&\frac{2n+1}{2^{n}n!}D^{n-1}\biggl\{\left(x^2-1\right)^{n-1}\biggl[
\left(n+1\right)x^2+n-1\biggr]\color{green}{-D\left[x\left(x^2-1\right)^n\right]+n\left(x^2-1\right)^{n}}\biggr\}=\\
=\;&\frac{2n+1}{2^{n}n!}D^{n-1}\biggl\{\left(x^2-1\right)^{n-1}\cdot 0\biggr\}=0.
\end{align}

Comment: Great answer. Thank you.

Comment: Could you provide some clarification about the [D, x] notation though? Thanks.

Comment: @AnalysisLover $[D,x]$ denotes the commutator $Dx-xD$. It literally means $[D,x]f= xD(f)-D(xf)$, where $f$ is any function of $x$.

Comment: I was also able to show that $xD^{n}(f)=(D^{n}\circ{x-nD^{n-1})(f)}$ with the general Leibniz Rule. That was the missing piece in my previous attempts at the proof. Thanks.

Comment: @AnalysisLover You are welcome. By the way you can also upvote answers in addition to accepting them.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not yet have enough reputation to upvote as I am a new user. I am planning to post my own solution to this problem. If it receives an upvote, I will have sufficient reputation to upvote your answer and will.

Answer (score 5):

Note that by Rodrigues' formula, $P_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2^{n+1}(n+1)!}D^{n+1}[(x^{2}-1)^{n+1}]$. Multiplying by $(n+1)$, we have:
\begin{align*}
&{\left(n+1\right)P_{n+1}(x)}={\left(n+1\right)\frac{1}{2^{n+1}(n+1)!}D^{n+1}[(x^{2}-1)^{n+1}]}\\
=\;&{\left(n+1\right)\frac{1}{2^{n}n!}D^{n}[x(x^{2}-1)^{n}]}\\
\end{align*}
Using the Leibniz rule:
\begin{align*}
=\;&{\left(n+1\right)\frac{xD^{n}[(x^{2}-1)^{n}]+nD^{n-1}[(x^{2}-1)^{n}]}{2^{n}n!}}\\
=\;&x(n+1)P^{n}(x)+\frac{n(n+1)}{2^{n}n!}D^{n-1}[(x^2-1)^n]\\
\end{align*}
Adding and subtracting $\frac{1}{2^{n}(n-1)!}xD^{n}[(x^2-1)^n]$ we get:
\begin{align*}
=\;&x(2n+1)P^{n}(x)+\frac{n(n+1)}{2^{n}n!}D^{n-1}[(x^2-1)^n]-\frac{1}{2^{n}(n-1)!}xD^{n}[(x^2-1)^n]\\
\end{align*}
Using L.G.'s observation (or deriving it with the Leibniz rule) we have:
\begin{align*}
=\;&x(2n+1)P^{n}(x)+\frac{(n+1)}{2^{n}(n-1)!}D^{n-1}[(x^2-1)^n]-\frac{1}{2^{n}(n-1)!}(D^{n}[x(x^2-1)^n]-nD^{n-1}[(x^2-1)^n])\\
=\;&x(2n+1)P^{n}(x)+\frac{2n}{2^{n}(n-1)!}D^{n-1}[(x^2-1)^{n}-x^{2}(x^{2}-1)^{n-1}]\\
=\;&x(2n+1)P^{n}(x)+\frac{n}{2^{n-1}(n-1)!}D^{n-1}[(x^2-1)^{n-1}(-1)]\\
=\;&x(2n+1)P^{n}(x)-nP^{n-1}(x).
\end{align*}

Comment: Nice answer! I have one question though. What is "L.G.'s observation" referring to?

Comment: @userE It refers to the observation that $[D^n, x]=nD^{n-1}$ which is substituted for $xD^{n-1}$ in the line right before the comment you are referencing. I haven’t looked at this post in years, but would guess that L.G. used to be username of the author of the other answer.